# How to run dos [ent.exe] and [fp8.exe] on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, ms-dos

This old chestnut again!

I'm trying to run Fourmilab's ent.exe and a file compression tool called fp8.exe.  These are both DOS command line utilities that I have successfully run on Windows 7. I can't run them properly under Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

I have Wine installed and it works with other Windows' stuff.  So I click on either fp8 or ent.  They both execute and a black terminal window opens.  The two packages take command line arguments, and I can see that they are effectively executing without the arguments.  I just see the help page for fp8, and a (for simplicity) black screen for ent.

So I fire up DOSBOX, and try to execute them from there.  Both programs report "This program cannon be run in DOS mode."  Well yes it can, as it does so on Windows, and they run non argumented under Wine.  As here:-

[image: fp8 executing under Wine]

How can I run them interactively on a command line so that I can supply various arguments to them?  I want to run:-

ent {this file}

ent -b {that file}

fp8 -8 {another}

and so on...

I looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738393/dosbox-trying-to-run-tlink-this-program-cannot-be-run-in-dos-mode-why) similar question, but it was unanswered.

Comment: are you sure they are opening with wine, not something else? right click the .exe and select "open with >> wine". If wine gives an error then be sure to move compatibility to DOS via wine configuration

Comment: That's a Win32 executable (see their website), so it won't run in dosbox.

Comment: @chaskes No, it run perfectly in Windows terminal as I've been running it for 2 years prior to ditching Windows.

Comment: have you tried right click >> open with wine @PaulUszak ?

Comment: A windows terminal program is not the same as a dos program.

Comment: @JamesTobin Pretty certain it's running in Wine.  Please see edit.

Comment: you could try it to make sure

Comment: @chaskes sorry for getting mixed up and pinging wrong person

Comment: @chaskes yes, I got mixed up. Meant to ping Paul, sorry

Comment: @JamesTobin Yes James, I open it via "Open With Wine Windows Program" by right clicking  it.  On my machine .exe is associated with Wine /Windows anyway so simply double clicking also works.

Comment: @PaulUszak By the way, it is easy to get `ent` to run natively in Linux without using Wine at all. Where did you get `fp8.exe` from?

Comment: @edwinksl from Fourmilab's website, http://www.fourmilab.ch/random

Comment: @PaulUszak I am asking about `fp8.exe`.

Comment: It's in their zip file on that page.

Comment: @PaulUszak That zip file only has `ent.exe`, not `fp8.exe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way would be to specify the full path to the executable and prepending `wine` before it.  Basically using file paths like this with the `wine` program, on the Terminal / command line:

```
wine /path/to/executable.exe [argument argument ...] PATH_TO_FILE_TO_USE
```

Note that not all CLI programs for Windows will correctly run in Wine - Wine may be a compatibility layer but there are many things which will not run under Wine.

---

This isn't really that hard.  The three example commands from above but with Wine formatting and such:

```
wine /path/to/ent.exe /path/to/{this file}

wine /path/to/ent.exe -b /path/to/{that file}

wine /path/to/fp8.exe -8 /path/to/{another}
```

Comment: Yes, this works already.  But how do I get to supply interactive arguments to them?  Is there a way through Wine that arguments can be passed?  Is there no way to just fire up ent.exe on a command line and then interact with it?  Is this not possible on Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by interactive arguments?  the application needs to be written in such a way to prompt and if not then it doesn't have that functionality.  Note that since we don't have these executables we can't attest to whether it could or couldn't work, but Wine is not DOS, and doesn't support all the same functionality that Windows would support.

Comment: With reference to my screen grab, how do I enter all the -8 , compress, decompress and filename stuff that you can see on the help page.

Comment: @PaulUszak The same way you would run the command on Windows, just add `wine` before the entire command.  It's the same as executing the command on Windows, providing the arguments in the correct location after the path to the executable.

Comment: Duh.  I didn't know that Wine ran on the command line.